# OCR using react native

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, ocr

my company is trying to create an OCR application i did some research in order for the OCR to scan the text it needs to take a picture first is there a way that it will automatically scan the text without taking a picture an real time scan. im using React Native by the way.

our company is trying to create an OCR android application. i did some research an found out that you need to take a picture first before it will scan the text. is there a way for it to scan the text automatically without taking a picture?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

- Building an OCR Application with React Native : https://medium.com/@aykutarslantas/building-an-ocr-application-with-react-native-5b7ea0903692
- Image To Text Conversion With React And Tesseract.js (OCR) : https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/06/image-text-conversion-react-tesseract-js-ocr/
- Extract Text from Image with OCR - React JS : https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/tutorials/html5-reactjs-extract-text-from-image-with-ocr.html

Using the react-native-camera library with the react-native-tesseract-ocr library to perform real-time OCR using Tesseract.js

```
  import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
  import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
  import { RNCamera } from 'react-native-camera';
  import RNTesseractOcr from 'react-native-tesseract-ocr';

  const App = () => {
   const [text, setText] = useState('');
   const camera = useRef(null);

   useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const result = await recognizeText('path/to/your/tesseract/language/tessdata', camera.current);
      setText(result.text);
    })();
   }, []);

  const recognizeText = async (tessdataPath, cameraRef) => {
    const data = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync();
    const result = await RNTesseractOcr.recognize(tessdataPath, data.uri);
    return result;
  };

  const handleCameraFrame = async (frame) => {
    if (!camera.current) return;

    const result = await recognizeText('path/to/your/tesseract/language/tessdata', camera.current);
    setText(result.text);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <RNCamera
        style={styles.preview}
        type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
        captureAudio={false}
        onCameraReady={() => console.log('Camera ready')}
        onFrame={handleCameraFrame}
        ref={camera}
      />
      <Text style={styles.text}>{text}</Text>
    </View>
  );
  };
    
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  preview: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 20,
    color: '#fff',
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  });
```